# How to use For Loop in Selenium IDE to loop through pages

Tags: php, selenium, web-testing, headless-browser

I would like to see my web pages to change automated from from page 1 to page 200 and i tried using php and javascript but nothing worked for using for loop. is there a way to use for loop in the page?

```
    <tr> 
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=5</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>link = 6;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>link &lt; 10;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>link</td>
    <td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>link = ${value}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>link++;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I wanted the link to be in a for loop from 1 to 100. I appreciate anyone who helps me.so far i tried to echo the page numbers but is there any way to loop through pages?

so far this is the output i got:

```
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | link=2 | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | link=3 | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | link=4 | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | link=5 | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | link=6 | |
[info] Executing: |getEval | link = 6; | |
[info] script is: link = 6;
[info] Executing: |while | link < 10; | |
[info] Executing: |storeEval | link | value |
[info] script is: link
[info] Executing: |echo | link = ${value} | |
[info] echo: link = 6
[info] Executing: |echo | {$Value} | |
[info] echo: {$Value}
[info] Executing: |getEval | link++; | |
[info] script is: link++;
[info] Executing: |endWhile | | |
[info] Executing: |while | link < 10; | |
[info] Executing: |storeEval | link | value |
[info] script is: link
[info] Executing: |echo | link = ${value} | |
[info] echo: link = 7
[info] Executing: |echo | {$Value} | |
```

Comment: _"but nothing worked"_ What errors did you get? Please include your attempts in your question as well, your current code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Actually I don't get what you are trieng to achive.. your code makes no sense.. maybe you should show us the page or more code of the page so we can get a better understand of what you want to achieve

Comment: i just need the numbers to be changed automatically and the numbers  are from pagination so i need the clickandwait to load all the pages from 1 to 100